# Does every connected $r$-regular bipartite graph contain a Hamiltonian cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Here's a quickie:

Let $r\ge2$. Does every connected $r$-regular bipartite graph contain a Hamiltonian cycle?

I've been playing around with this for almost an hour, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Horton graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horton_graph) is cubic, 3-connected, bipartite, and non-Hamiltonian. There is a conjecture of Barnette (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnette%27s_conjecture)) that cubic, 3-connected, bipartite, planar graphs are Hamiltonian. This has yet to be proven or disproven.