# Is there any regular, balanced, connected bipartite graph that does not contain any Hamiltonian cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

> In a set of balanced, connected bipartite graphs, all with regularity $r \ge 2$, is it possible that there exists a bipartite graph that does not contain a Hamiltonian cycle ?

**My argument**: The bipartite graph is balanced, so both of the partition has the same number of vertices. It's regularity $r \ge 2$ and the graph is connected, that means we can switch between the partitions, so there is a Hamiltonian path. Lets say that we have followed the Hamiltonian path from vertex $u$ and reached to a vertex $v$ and exhausted all the vertices, now how do I prove that there must be an edge that will take me back to $u$ from $v$?

I am getting lost with this construction of the "Hamiltonian cycle".

So does this mean that there can be such bipartite graph (connected, balanced, $r \ge 2$ regular) that does not contain a Hamiltonian cycle? **If yes, can someone give me a concrete example?**

**N.B.:** $r$-regular: every edge is $r$-degree.

Comment: When you say the graph has regularity $r\ge 2$, do you mean that the degree of each vertex is $r$?

Comment: What if the graph is not connected?

Comment: @Casteels It's corrected, the graph is connected.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius yes.

Comment: Hmm, actually we have this already: [Does every connected $r$-regular bipartite graph contain a Hamiltonian cycle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830904/does-every-connected-r-regular-bipartite-graph-contain-a-hamiltonian-cycle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a concrete non-Hamiltonian 3-regular bipartite graph:

```
          -----X-----
         /     |     \
        O      O      O
       / \    / \    / \
      X-O-X  X-O-X  X-O-X
      | | |  | | |  | | |
      O-X-O  O-X-O  O-X-O
       \ /    \ /    \ /
        X      X      X
         \     |     /
          -----O-----
```

Comment: gulp, have you just broke a record? Ellingham-Horton graph has 54 vertices and wiki says it's the lowest!

Comment: @ramgorur: That's the smallest known _3-connected_ example, which this graph isn't.

Comment: @ramgorur: (And actually Wikipedia says a [50-vertex example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeorgesGraph.html) is known)